# semantic ui Pagination not Responsive

Tags: datatables, responsive, semantic-ui

I have using datatable with semantic ui for displaying tables. but the pagination is not responsive.

here is my sample [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7gdk29o3/2/)

```
`?`
```

Comment: can you simplify your fiddle? just have 4-5 data elements so users can navigate the HTML easily

Answer (score 0):

To set the pagination horizontally and nicer responsive I did a quick and dirty change. I just removed the class `stackable` in the minimized file:

> dataTables.semanticui.min.js

Responsive Result:

before:

```
[...]<div class="ui stackable pagination menu"/>[...]
```

[image]

after:

```
[...]<div class="ui pagination menu"/>[...]
```

[image]

Note: This quick and dirty change has effects to all semantic UI dataTable paginations!

Comment: For this i have used custom pagination. Instead of default datatables pagination.